# Android custom menu navigation drawer background did not show on start up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am working on my Android app to make a custom menu items for navigation drawer. Everything is working fine especially when I click on the menu items, but when I run on the app, I could not see the pink background start up in the navigation drawer as I can see it is empty.

It should show like this:

[image]

But this is what it show right now:

[image]

Here is the mainactivity:

```
public static DrawerLayout drawer;
public static NavigationView navigationView;
private ArrayList<MenuNavItem> list= new ArrayList<>();
private MenuNavItem mailfolder = null;
private NavController navController;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    ArrayList<MenuNavItem> list= new ArrayList<>();
    MenuNavItem MenuInbox = new MenuNavItem("Inbox", total_inbox, R.drawable.ic_baseline_inbox_24);
    list.add(MenuInbox);
    list.add(MenuImportant);
    list.add(MenuOutbox);

    adapter = new CustomMenuAdapter(context, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_inbox)
        .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
        .build();
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        style="@style/Widget.Custom.NavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

navigation_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I select on the menu item, it will show the pink background with no problem.

[image]

I don't know why it wont show on startup when I run on the app.

Do you know why it will not show on startup when I run it?

Are there a way if I can get them to start up when I run?

If so, could you please show me an example what is the correct way to use to get them to run on startup using my own custom menu??

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment on Mohsen's answer having an issue: Cannot resolve symbol 'android:navigationView' try include this in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
//your version
    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with this, the navigation item still don't show pink background on launch unless when I select on the item.

Comment: Did you try putting this: android:background="@color/pink" inside of LinearLayout on your navigation_drawer.xml file?

Comment: No I havent try it, i need example code to get the navigation drawer selected item to work on launch the app?